# assertEquals Precision

Tags: java, junit, precision, assert

I am confused regarding the delta/precision in `assertEquals`.
I understand that `0.034` will give me the precision for my division code, as shown below:

```
public void testDivide() {
        assertEquals(3.0, Arithmetic.divide(12.0, 4.0), 0.0);
        assertEquals(3.3, Arithmetic.divide(10.0, 3.0), 0.034);

        //fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
```

However, I tried to change it to `0.03`, the test failed. On the other hand, when I change it to `0.04`, it succeeded, or even if I change it to `0.034444` and so forth, it will succeed.
May I know what does the number mean, and how do we use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using:

[`assertEquals`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double)`(double expected, double actual, double epsilon)`

Since [doubles may not be exactly equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) in any language (precision issues), epsilon allows you to describe how close they have to be.

Epsilon is *defined* as the maximal deviation from the `expected` result:

```
Math.abs(expected - actual) < epsilon
```

So in essence it allows you to deviate from the `expected` outcome (`3.0` or `3.3` in your cases) by
`Arithmetic.divide(12.0, 4.0) - 3.0 = 3.0 - 3.0 = 0` and
 `Arithmetic.divide(10.0, 3.0) - 3.3 ≈ 3.3333333 -3.3 ≈ 0.3333333` respectively.

So in the first one as you see, there is actually no need for an epsilon since the `expected` and `actual` results are exactly the same.
In the second one you should allow some deviation as you see that the `actual` result is approximately `>` by `0.33333` than the `expected` one.

Comment: isn't epsilon mean the precision?

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote :) It is the precision allowed in your specific `assert`

Answer (score 3):

According to: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double, double, double)

```
**delta** - the maximum delta between expected and actual for which both numbers are still considered equal.
```

for delta = 0.3
Now, `Arithmetic.divide(10.0,3.0) - 3.0` = `0.333..` which is `greater than 0.3`, so `assertEqual()` fails

for delta = 0.4
Now, `Arithmetic.divide(10.0,3.0) - 3.0` = `0.333..` which is `LESSER than 0.4`, so `assertEqual()` passes